# threejs, div.appendChild & dynamic resize

Tags: svg, three.js, resize, gsap

I'm trying to resize the canvas created by three.js but as soon as I uncomment the 6 lines concerning three.js in the wrapResize2 function the cube disappears.

If I look at the chrome-console it seems it doesn't find the appended canvas element.

And if I inspect the elements in Chrome I see that the canvas element is not there anymore.

I don't know why but when those 6 resize lines are there the threejs canvas is not appended anymore.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #wrap {margin: auto}
        .abs {position: absolute}
    </style
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap" class="abs">
    <svg id="back" class="abs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>
            <filter id="noise">
                <feTurbulence baseFrequency=".1" type="fractalNoise" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect width="500" height="500" filter="url(#noise)"/>
    </svg>
    <div id="sriJs" class="abs">
    </div>
    <svg id="front" class="abs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>
            <style>
                .cls-1 {
                    fill: #f0f;
                    opacity: 0.3;
                }
                .cls-2 {
                    fill: aqua;
                    opacity: 0.4;
                }
                .cls-3 {
                    fill: #ff0;
                    opacity: 0.5;
                }
            </style>
        </defs>
        <path d="M0,0V500H500V0ZM245,490H10V255H245Zm0-245H10V10H245ZM490,490H255V255H490Zm0-245H255V10H490Z"/>
        <rect class="cls-1" x="10" y="10" width="235" height="235"/>
        <rect class="cls-2" x="255" y="10" width="235" height="235"/>
        <rect class="cls-3" x="10" y="255" width="235" height="235"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fullScreen = 1,
    wrapWidth = 500,
    wrapHeight = 500,
    rotationX = 2,
    rotationY = 2,
    rotationZ = 2,
    animTime = 30,
//-------------------
    idQsel = function (e) {return document.querySelector('#' + e)},
    mf3 = function mf3(v){return Math.floor(v*1000)/1000},
    wrap = idQsel('wrap'),
    sriJs = idQsel('sriJs'),
    back = idQsel('back'),
    front = idQsel('front'),
    sriJsW,sriJsH,
    iifeMain = (function() {
        var camera, scene, renderer, cube,
        init = function () {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, sriJsW/sriJsH, 1, 20000);
            camera.position.z = 250;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true});
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(sriJsW,sriJsH);
            sriJs.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        },
        cubeInit = function () {
            var mat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(),
            cubeSize = 100;
            cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize), mat);
            scene.add( cube );
        },
        animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        },
        render = function () {renderer.render(scene, camera);},

        cubeRotation = function () {
            var obj = cube.rotation;
            TweenMax.to(cube.rotation, animTime/2, {
                x: obj.x + rotationX,
                y: obj.y + rotationY,
                z: obj.z + rotationZ,
                onComplete: cubeRotation
            });
        },
            
        wrapResize2 = function(wW,wH,cW,cH) {
            if ((wH < cH) || (fullScreen==1)) {
                wrap.style.width = wW + 'px';
                wrap.style.height = wH  + 'px';
                back.style.width = wW + 'px';
                back.style.height = wH  + 'px';
                front.style.width = wW + 'px';
                front.style.height = wH  + 'px';
                //renderer.setSize(wW,wH);
                //camera.aspect = wW/wH;
                //camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                sriJsW = wW;
                sriJsH = wH;
            } else {
                wrap.style.height = cH + 'px';
                wrap.style.width = cW + 'px';
                back.style.height = cH  + 'px';
                back.style.width = cW + 'px';
                front.style.height = cH  + 'px';
                front.style.width = cW + 'px';
                //renderer.setSize(cW,cH);
                //camera.aspect = cW/cH;
                //camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                sriJsH = cH;
                sriJsW = cW;
            }
        },
        wrapResize = function() {
            var wrapWbyH = wrapWidth/wrapHeight,
            winW = window.innerWidth,
            winH = window.innerHeight,
            winWbyH = winW / winH;
            if (winWbyH > wrapWbyH) winW = winH * wrapWbyH;
            else winH = winW / wrapWbyH;
            wrapResize2(winW,winH,wrapWidth,wrapHeight);
        },
        winit = function() {
            wrap.style.top = 0;
            wrap.style.right = 0;
            wrap.style.bottom = 0;
            wrap.style.left = 0;

            wrapResize();

            init();
            cubeInit();
            animate();
            cubeRotation();
        };
        window.addEventListener('load', winit, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize', wrapResize, false);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', winit, false);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me?

I made a codepen with the 6 lines uncommented at : https://codepen.io/trufo/pen/powgRpB

Cheers

Michael

ps: disregard my comment below about renaming. I managed to do it in the code snippet above.

Comment: I replaced all occurences of the word canvas by wrap in my code. But homebot won't let me do that. It's complaining about wrong identations. But the code is the same. Anyway for a more accurate code one should look at my codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do the same thing but without appendChild. I put the canvas directly in the wrap div...

```
    <canvas id="cnv" class="abs">
    </canvas>
```

... and then use it in the renderer var.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true, canvas: cnv })
```

see codepen here:
https://codepen.io/trufo/pen/qBjbzqd